# Deleted image still shows in android gallery untill I restart the emaulator

Tags: android, emulation

I'm deleting a file as such

```
File fileToDelete =  new File("filepath");
Boolean fileDeleted =  fileToDelete.delete();
```

The fileDeleted is true and when I check the DDMS the file is not there but if I click on the gallery it still shows the image that was just deleted. I have to restart the emulator to see the change.

Is there any way to see the changes without having to restart the emaulator? I'm using eclipse

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is to do with how Gallery shows the Image files. Image file's Thumbnails are cached in the MediaStore and all the details are present in the Mediastore contentProvider.

Deleting the file will not update this database. But when you restart the emulator, Mediascanning is done by android. If MediaScanning can be triggered , gallery will stop showing the files

Comment: I don't have an android on hand I use an iphone :).  Is this how it would work on an actual phone? The image would still be visible until the phone is turned off and then back on?

Comment: Yes. if you do not update the MediaStore . You should probably follow @zapl 's answer to make this right

Comment: I did this and it fixed the issue
//Broadcast the Media Scanner Intent to trigger it
 sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri
                    .parse("file://"
                            + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));

Answer (score 17):

The gallery is using Android's media database to display the list of media. Deleting the file will not be reflected in the database until it scans the filesystem again. That is for example done after rebooting.

You can either delete the file directly through the database or force it to scan the file or folder you just deleted.

```
File fileToDelete =  new File("filepath");
boolean fileDeleted =  fileToDelete.delete();

// request scan    
Intent scanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
scanIntent.setData(Uri.fromFile(fileToDelete));
sendBroadcast(scanIntent);
```

Comment: @hadi I think you need to scan the folder your file was in for this to actually work.

Comment: i have changed the path of file actually and its hidden now. if i scan for the old file it wont delete the thumbnail from gallery

Answer (score 2):

I use the following code (which is also much like my code for creating a video which also tells the media system about file changes and correctly updates the Gallery):

```
private void deleteVideo(String videoUrl)
{
    File videoFile = new File(videoUrl);
    if (!videoFile.delete())
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to delete " + videoUrl);
    }
    else
    {
        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(mContext,new String[] { videoUrl }, null, new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() 
        {
            public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) 
            {
                Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
                Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
            }
        });
    }
}
```